# Why do I need to use buttonStyle instead of android:buttonStyle with API level 16?

Tags: android

I was struggling to make a button style work with API level 16 (with API level 22 was working like a charm). I solved it replacing `android:buttonStyle` with `buttonStyle`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item> -->
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
</style>
```

Now it works with both API levels, but now my question is:
Why is this happening?

Comment: really? Sir, you could have hit the docs and life will be good

Comment: @Elltz I actually did, maybe I had to employ more time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

```
item name="buttonStyle"
```

is for support library compatibility which your current Theme supports. It is also used on defining other items like actionbar https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

I suggest you define both of it to make it compatible to very wide range of devices