# android appcompat style for toolbar to match actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, toolbar

I am using the android support library ToolBar and would like to use the same background color to match the ActionBar.

I looked in the support library souce code and found the ActionBar style I want to use:

```
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

But when I put it in my layout as a style to the toolbar, it doesn't work:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/actiontoolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid"
        />
```

However, if I just use "android:background" instead of "style" then it works:

```
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work when I reference the support library style in the toolbar layout.  I am using appcompat 22.2.0 in AndroidStudio.
I've also tried the following and they don't work either:

```
    android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid"
    app:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the toolbar requires a theme. Firstly define your color attributes in a theme with appcompat parent.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"> 
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Just to make sure, make use of color values.

In toolbar

```
app:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

Also, make sure you have

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

IDE may ask you to auto correct this

The final look of your toolbar will be

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/actiontoolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    />
```

And as for an **update** from Gabriele: With appcompat 22.1.0 you can use

```
android:theme
```

Comment: With appcompat 22.1.0 you can use android:theme in the Toolbar

Comment: @Sheychan What do you mean I'm referring to a theme?  Theme and styles are the same, only difference is how you apply them to the app, activitiy, or view.

I already tried those combinations and they are still not working.
app:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid"
android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid"
style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid"
None of the above work. 
I am using appcompat 22.2.0 with AndroidStudio

Comment: @Sheychan It doesn't work.  Defining your own theme or style still doesn't work.  I already tried it.  Somehow the line <item name="background">...</item> never gets used.  Like I mentioned in my question, it works if there is an android: prefix either as a standalone or as part of a style.  <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item> works.  So why is "android:background" being used instead of "background"?  I can believe "android:background" being used on newer API but on API where Toolbar or ActionBar doesn't exist, shouldn't "background" be used?

Comment: I do see the attribute "background" being available since API 1.  Could this be why?  Anyone know for sure if that's how attributes are being applied?

Comment: This might answer that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001381/why-do-i-need-to-use-buttonstyle-instead-of-androidbuttonstyle-with-api-level-1/32001469#32001469